# SPListItem id from SPField object

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am working on create a custom field type and for implementation issue I need to retrieve the ID of the `SPListItem` in the `SPField` class which belong to these field type but I can't retrieve it.

For example:

```
public class myField:SPFieldText
{
    // I need ListItemID in this class
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to directly retrieve the ItemID for the field in this way - what is it you need to do (there might be another way)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a solution but I've tried another solution which is 
I can get the ID of the item in the New and Edit forms so I saved the ID and the field value as a one value separated by '/' and in the SPFieldText class I've been able to retrieve the ID value from the value of the field

Answer (score 1):

SPFieldText is an SPField, which is the schema definition for a field. Its like saying, given an SQL create table statement, give me the id of row x. Can't be done.

I think the logic you are trying to perform should be done in an event receiver, so say when an item is saved, you take the ID and add it to the text field.

Comment: Thanks djeeg, but I can get it directly in the rendering template control so I can display it in the display, new and edit forms. My only problem is when make a view of it, it use GetValueAsHtml() in SPFieldText class so I need the id of the item at this level